# How to launch exports.function in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the routes folder of a Node.Js app I have a file entries.js which has the following function:

```
exports.form = function(req, res){
   res.render('post', { title: 'Post' });
};
```

Is it actually possible to launch something like this from another exports function in the same file, such as:

```
  exports.something = function(req, res){
        this.form(req.res);
  };
```

Where this.form refers to exports.form function in the same file.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just use `exports.form(req, res)`?

Comment: Yes, `this` would have your property `form` do a `console.log(this)` and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` by default will point to the object whose member the function is. In this case, both functions are members of the same object, thus using `this.form` should work as expected.

The exceptions to this rule are when the function in question is used together with `bind`, `call`, or `apply`.

Comment: This did not work, actually - when I try to point to it it says it's not found. Just to say again - I've got routes/entries.js in my express Node.Js app and there I have exports.save = function () {} which I want to call from exports.submit function. how would i do it?

Comment: Why do you persist in trying to use `this`? Is your goal to use `this` or to have a module in which you can call one function from another one?

Comment: @deemeetree without seeing your exact code I don't know what's going on. It works perfectly fine on my end with a simple test case http://pastie.org/9223505 - require that, call `foo`, output has both logs.